# Axler's proof that a subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is finite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Theorem 2.26 in Axler's book states:

> Every subspace of a finite-dimensional vector space is finite-dimensional.

I'm ok with most of the steps of the proof, but I have two questions concerning it. I'll quickly just sketch the proof he writes. If $U \subset V$ is the trivial subspace, it's spanned by the empty set, which is of course finite. If not, we can pick a nonzero $v_1 \in U$. If $\mathrm{span}(v_1) = U$, we're done; otherwise, we pick $v_2 \in U \setminus \mathrm{span}(v_1)$, and continue inductively, adding vectors until we span all of $V$ and noting that, by construction, the new list is linearly independent.

Axler comments that this algorithm terminates eventually because, as he proved earlier, the length of any linearly independent list is less than or equal to the length of any spanning set. I'm ok with the proof of that result, but I have two questions regarding this.

(1) I'm not totally sure how he compares the set of vectors generated by this process with a spanning set. I think the argument is as follows. As $V$ is finite-dimensional, it admits a finite spanning set, $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ for some $n \geq 1$. At every step of this algorithm, I picked a set of linearly independent vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ in $U$, but $U$ is a subset of $V$, so I can view it as a set of vectors in $V$. If they're linearly independent in $U$, they're also linearly independent in $V$, so I can compare the list $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ with $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ and say $k \leq n$. Is this the correct line of thinking?

(2) The algorithm makes sense to me, but I'm wondering if I can shorten the proof as follows. Let $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ be a finite spanning set for $V$. If $U \subset V$ is a subset, I can write any $u$ in $U$ in terms of the $w_i$. If $u \in U$, $u \in V$, and the $w_i$ span $V$. As I can do this for any $u \in U$, this same finite spanning set for $V$ spans $U$, probably with some redundancy, so $U$ is also finite-dimensional. Is there anything wrong with this argument?

Comment: (1) Yes, that's correct. (2) the problem is that the vectors $w_i$ are not necessarily in $U$ so they don't count as 'spanning set for $U$'.